# Include count of linked records in OData result

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, wcf-data-services, odata

I've got a table "Events" with a linked table "Registrations", and I want to create an OData service that returns records from the Events table, plus the number of registrations for each event. The data will be consumed client-side in JavaScript, so I want to keep the size of the returned data down and not include all linked registration records completely.

For example:

```
ID  Title      Date            Regs
1   Breakfast  01.01.01 12:00  4
2   Party      01.01.01 20:00  20
```

I'm building the service with ASP.NET MVC4. The tables are in an MSSQL database. I am really just getting started with OData and LINQ.

I tried using the WebAPI OData system first (using classes of EntitySetController) but was getting cryptic server errors as soon as I included the Registrations table in the entity set. ("The complex type 'Models.Registration' refers to the entity type 'Models.Event' through the property 'Event'.")

I had more success building a WCF OData system, and can request event information and information on related registrations.

However, I have no clue how to include the aggregate count information in the event result set. Do I need to create a custom entity set that will be the source for the OData service? I probably included too litte information here for finding a solution, but I don't really know where to look. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was actually very simple; I created a View in SQL Server that returns the table including the registration counts. Never thought about using a view, since I've never used them before...

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to make an extra request per `Event`, you could query `http://.../YourService.svc/Events(<key>)/Registrations/$count` (or `http://.../YourService.svc/Events(<key>)/$links/Registrations?$inlinecount=allpages` if you're also using the links to the `Registration` entities).

Examples of both of these approaches on a public service:

[http://services.odata.org/V3/OData/OData.svc/Suppliers(0)/Products/$count](http://services.odata.org/V3/OData/OData.svc/Suppliers%280%29/Products/%24count)

[http://services.odata.org/V3/OData/OData.svc/Suppliers(0)/$links/Products?$inlinecount=allpages&$format=json](http://services.odata.org/V3/OData/OData.svc/Suppliers%280%29/%24links/Products?%24inlinecount=allpages&%24format=json)

I'm guessing that you'd prefer this information to come bundled together with the rest of the `Events` response though. It's not ideal, but you could issue a query along these lines:

[http://services.odata.org/V3/OData/OData.svc/Suppliers?$format=json&$expand=Products&$select=Products/ID,*](http://services.odata.org/V3/OData/OData.svc/Suppliers?%24format=json&%24expand=Products&%24select=Products/ID,%2a)

I'm expanding `Products` (analogous to your `Registrations`) and selecting `Products/ID` in order to force the response to include an array that is the same size as the nested `Products` collection. I don't care about `ID` -- I just chose a piece of data that would be small. With this JSON response, your javascript client can get the length of the `Products` array and use that as the number of `Products` that are linked to the given `Supplier`.

(Note: to have your service support `$select` queries using WCF Data Services, you'll need to include this line when you initialize the service: `config.DataServiceBehavior.AcceptProjectionRequests = true;`)

Edit to add: The approach using $expand and $select won't be guaranteed to give you the correct count if your server does server-driving paging. In general, there isn't a simple single-response way to do what you're asking for in OData v3, but in OData v4, this will be possible with the new expand/select syntax.

Comment: Thanks! I am going to give both of these approaches a try on Tuesday when I'm back at work. They seem like very good solutions.

Answer (score 1):

i'm using oData v4 and i used this syntax :

```
var url = '.../odata/clients?$expand=Orders($count=true)';
// ...
```

a field called **Orders@odata.count** has been added to the response entity which contains the correct count.
and now to access the JSON property containing a dash you have to do it like this :

```
var ordersCount = response.value['Orders@odata.count'];
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I used this to get the *child* count without returning the entities:

```
/Parents$expand=Children($count=true;$top=0)
```

Comment: This works pretty well.  I had a complex query that was taking 18s to perform because of expands.  Setting ($count=true;$top=0) dropped the query to 1.2s, and reduced data transfer by 75%.  I wish count could done without requiring and expand in the first place, but for now this works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

Can you edit your Event model and add a RegistrationCount property?  That'd be the simplest way I think

Comment: I guess I could, but I don't know how I would fill that property with the aggregated count from the registrations table...